# Does making pictures with bigger dimensions than actually needed enhance their quality?

Tags: website-design, image-quality, paper-size, dimensions

### Clarifications

- I need the picture for my website, that is, it'll be for online purposes.
- I'll be using PNG because I need transparency.

  **[EDIT]**
- I need a "JOIN" written on a monochromatic sketch-like picture.

### Question

Suppose I need a 300x200 blip-type of image. I can design on an exact 300x200 paper, but if I rather make a 600x400 pixels image and then shorten it, would it be of better quality?

Or, if I make a 300x200 picture, would that be of best-quality for the allotted space?

Comment: It depends on what you do, how you do it, and why. It can help or not.

Comment: So there's not really a technique like "start with bigger dimensions for small pictures to enhance their quality" and making a 300x200 picture will be fine?

Comment: @joojaa: Also, check the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does making pictures with bigger dimensions than actually needed enhance their quality?

No.

In the end, you're still left with the same amount of image data as if you had started at that size.

Comment: Image size and data are no constraints. I just want to know the possible impacts on the quality, or detail. For example, if you enlarge a picture, it looses quality. In the same way, a bigger picture will have more details, so will pressing that in a small place better than making the image of the original size?

Comment: @Abhimanyu again, no. "you're still left with the same amount of image data as if you had started at that size". Not sure how to make that any clearer.

Comment: Oh now I get it. So if the picture, actually created at AxB is pressed down in a space of A/2xB/2, then the image is as detailed as an actual A/2xB/2 sized image would've been, right?

Comment: @Abhimanyu in terms of pixels, yes. Whether you start with a 300x300px, or start with a 3000x30000px image and shrink it down to 300x300px, you end up with the same thing.

Comment: That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what software you use, making a bigger picture for the "master" can be useful. While reducing the size with a different program from the one used to create the image can sometimes cause issues, it is MUCH harder to take a small image and make it larger.

That said if you create the image in photoshop, I would definitely suggest using an even multiple of the dimensions (2x or 4x as big) as the desired eventual size. Also be sure to reduce the size in your image editing software, not with some other program.

Finally depending on your software it is probably worthwhile to do a quick test to make sure it will come out the way you want. If creating an image at doublesize and reducing it makes the final product look bad, better to find out early and just make the image the "correct" size from the get go.

Software and situation both affect the answer though, so what works for one project may not work for another.

Comment: I'll be using Inkscape, but my query is different. Is it possible that a compressed image (like a AxB image thrust inside a A/2xB/2 space) will make it look more detailed?

Comment: @Abhimanyu inkscape is vector = original size is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, that was meaningless. We're talking about pictures. Of course I'll "export" the picture as a PNG and won't upload the Inkscape's original SVG file!

Answer (score 0):

I would create the image with the dimensions you are going to use. Creating a larger image then cutting the size can cause the image to look worse because of downsampling.

I'm not sure if thats what your looking for. What are you talking about 300 x 200 paper?

Comment: and are you using Photoshop or similar image editing software for this? are we talking 300x200 pixels?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about. Is creating a bigger image than required enhance the quality? Or worsen it? Any software, for that matter. BTW I will be using Inkscape.